# setasign/fpdf and setasign/fpdi to password protect a PDF in PHP

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I am having some trouble using the setasign/fpdf and setasign/fpdi with fpdf/fpdf to password protect an uploaded pdf file.

So far I have this in my composer.json

```json
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.8",
        "fpdf/fpdf": "^1.85",
        "setasign/fpdf": "1.8.*",
        "setasign/fpdi": "^2.0",
        "setasign/fpdi-protection": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

and this on the page that handles the php.

```php
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
$pdf = new Fpdi();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('book.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
$permissions = array(
    'print' => false,
    'copy' => false,
    'modify' => false,
    'annot-forms' => false
);
$pdf->SetProtection($permissions);
$pdf->Output('protected_pdf.pdf', 'D');
```

but then I get the following error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Fpdi' not found in /home/`

If i omit `$pdf->SetProtection($permissions);` then the script runs normally and the pdf is outputted.

```php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi-protection/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('book.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
$permissions = array(
    'print' => false,
    'copy' => false,
    'modify' => false,
    'annot-forms' => false
);
$pdf->SetProtection($permissions);
$pdf->Output('protected_pdf.pdf', 'D');
```

also gives the same error.

```php
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
require_once('vendor/fpdf/fpdf/src/Fpdf/Fpdf.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi-protection/src/FpdiProtection.php');
require_once('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

$sourceFile = 'book.pdf';
$outputFile = 'book2.pdf';

$password = 'your_password';

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($sourceFile);

for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
    $importedPage = $pdf->importPage($pageNumber);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($importedPage);
}

$pdf->SetProtection(array(), $password);

$pdf->Output($outputFile, 'F');
```

also tried.

Comment: how to pass the password to the browser to not show the password dialog box that asks the user to enter the password? how to handle it by code?

Comment: I used https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ and by customizing the dialog I got what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you get the same error message in all examples but they are different. The method `setProtection()` is not available in the default FPDI class. Stay at the composer installation and use the class of FpdiProtection:

```
<?php
use setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection;

// setup the autoload function
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$pdf = new FpdiProtection();
$ownerPassword = $pdf->setProtection(
    FpdiProtection::PERM_PRINT | FpdiProtection::PERM_COPY,
    'the user password',
    'the owner password'
);
```